# How do I get the latest file of the same name from a folder?

Tags: python-3.x

I have different files, some may have the same name, I need to select latest file of each.
I have this code:

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

path = r'C:\Work\files\TestFolders\WebIQ'
files_path = os.path.join(path, '*')
files = []

# Get the latest Billing Code file
for i in os.listdir(path):
    if 'Billing Code' in i:
        # files.append(i)
        files = sorted(glob.iglob(i), key=os.path.getctime, reverse=True)[0]
```

I'm struggling to get in right inside the IF Statement, I have 3 Billing Code files, I need to get the latest, and my if statement does returns all three

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code modifications will provide your solution.

```
# Get the latest Billing Code file
for i in glob.iglob(files_path):
    if 'Billing Code' in i:
        # files.append(i)
files = sorted(files, key=os.path.getctime, reverse=True)[0]
```